# How to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica does not give me the correct solution (-1) for this equation:

```
Solve[9^(x + 4) == 27^(1 - x), x]
```

Do I miss something or is Solve the wrong approach here? Why?

Comment: `Solve[9^(x + 4) == 27^(1 - x), x, Reals]` All those solutions are right too ...

Answer (score 2):

Amplifying on @belisarius' excellent answer

eqn = 9^(x + 4) == 27^(1 - x);

In the following, C[1] is an arbitrary integer constant

```
sol1 = Assuming[Element[C[1], Integers], 
  Solve[9^(x + 4) == 27^(1 - x)] // Simplify]
```

> {{x -> -1 + (2 I [Pi] C[1])/Log[3]}, {x -> (    2 I [Pi] C[1] +
>   Log[-(1/3) (-1)^(1/5)])/Log[3]}, {x -> (    2 I [Pi] C[1] + Log[1/3
>   (-1)^(2/5)])/Log[3]}, {x -> (    2 I [Pi] C[1] + Log[-(1/3)
>   (-1)^(3/5)])/Log[3]}, {x -> (    2 I [Pi] C[1] + Log[1/3
>   (-1)^(4/5)])/Log[3]}}

Substituting the solutions back into the equation to verify that they satisfy it

```
And @@ Assuming[Element[C[1], Integers], eqn /. sol1 // Simplify]
```

> True

If you set the arbitrary constant C[1] to zero your expected solution is evident

```
sol1 /. C[1] -> 0
```

> {{x -> -1}, {x -> Log[-(1/3) (-1)^(1/5)]/Log[3]}, {x -> Log[1/3
>   (-1)^(2/5)]/    Log[3]}, {x -> Log[-(1/3) (-1)^(3/5)]/Log[3]}, {x ->
>   Log[1/3 (-1)^(4/5)]/    Log[3]}}

```
% // N
```

> {{x -> -1.}, {x -> -1. - 2.28768 I}, {x -> -1. + 1.14384 I}, {x -> -1.
>   - 1.14384 I}, {x -> -1. + 2.28768 I}}

Restricting solutions to be real as recommended by @belisarius, forces C[1] to be zero and only the one of the soutions remains.

```
Solve[9^(x + 4) == 27^(1 - x), x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -1}}